# How to make ranger's image/pdf preview persist in terminal?

Tags: terminal, pdf, preview, ranger

Just got image/pdf preview working in [ranger](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ranger), but I've noticed that when moving my mouse away from the ranger terminal window, the preview disappears. More annoying than this is that you can't run commands with the preview still displayed.

For instance I would like to preview the file, and then `:rename` it. As soon as any key is pressed (<kbd>Shift</kbd> in this case) the preview vanishes and I have to navigate to another file and then back to the file I want to preview.

I'm using the [st](https://st.suckless.org/) terminal emulator and the default `set preview_image_method w3m`.

What's going on here? Any way to fix this?

**EDIT:** Would also be happy to learn about any alternatives to ranger that can achieve the above.

Comment: I'm also using the `i3wm` and should mention that refreshing the config files or `i3` altogether with `Super+c` and `Super+r` will re-display the pdf. So after having the pdf be previewed, you can `:rename` and then `Super+c` to see the preview again. But you need to do this each time you press another key.